# Entity Framework : entityTypeConfiguration set prop value only on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I would expect that when using `ValueGeneratedOnUpdate` the specific value generator would only be called if the entity has been updated (so the entity already exists).

Instead it seems that the value is generated on add as well.

This is how I'm configuring the create and update props

```
builder.Property(self => self.CreatedAt)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .HasValueGenerator<UtcTimeValueGenerator>();

builder.Property(self => self.UpdatedAt)
    .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate()
    .HasDefaultValue(null)
    .HasValueGenerator<UtcTimeValueGenerator>();
```

Seed data.

```
builder.HasData(new List<Device>
{
    new Device
    {
        Id = 1,
        ParkingLotId = 1,
        Serial = "test",
        SigfoxSerial = "test"
    }
});
```

Generator

```
public class UtcTimeValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTime>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override DateTime Next(EntityEntry entry)
        => DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Using IEntityTypeConfiguration only, can a datetime propery be set for a specific column only if the entry already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, you can use a `Nullable<DateTime>` generator. And in the `Next` function you can check the state and decide whether to generate a new value or not.

```
public class UtcTimeValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTime?>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override DateTime Next(EntityEntry entry)
        => entry.State == EntityState.Modified ? DateTime.UtcNow : null;
}
```